# How to get 2D size of 3D model in XNA?

Tags: c#, windows, xna

I have a 3D model loaded with `model = Content.Load<Model>("cube")` and i need to get the size of that object after it gets projected to the viewport.
I know that i can use `Viewport.Project()`.But that works for a single point and what i need is a rectangle.Something i can draw a square brackets around.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of a couple of ways of doing this. My suggestion would be to find an upper corner and a lower corner of the model, and project those onto the viewport.

You could do this using the BoundingSphere of the model's Meshes for example. If it's a cube, as above, you could just go through the vertices one by one (obviously after aligning to the camera). Using that, you could draw a rectangle in screen space that will at least encompass the entire model, but perhaps a greater area as well depending on the shape.